# Not able to use input or buttons in SAP web app with Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-python

I am creating a test for an SAP web app with Playwright. I am having trouble to have it click on buttons or use the inputs of the selected IDs with Playwright. It selects (highlights) the buttons and input fields correctly, but then nothing happens.

This happens with all fields and buttons in other SAP apps as well. Am I on the wrong element? How do I select the correct element/layer of the input or button?

I tried Typescript and Python the behavior is the same.

My code is:

```
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test"

test.only("initial test", async ({ page }) => {
  test.setTimeout(600000)
  await page.goto("https://*some*intranet*site")
  const mail = "myname@mycompany.com"
  await page.type("#i0116", mail)
  await page.click("text=Next")
  await page.pause()
// Both not working:
  await page.type('#__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-inner', '12:01')
  await page.fill('#__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-inner', '12:01')
})
```

The input tag looks like this:

```
<input id="__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-inner" placeholder="HH:mm" value="10:54" role="combobox" aria-labelledby="__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-labelledby" aria-roledescription="Zeiteingabe" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-clocks" autocomplete="off" class="sapMInputBaseInner">
```

[image]

Comment: Try to click 2 times. And not sure, but think you have function page.fill() for textboxes.

Comment: I tried with page.dblclick() and page.fill() but it does the same. I guess it is not the right selector.

Comment: The `page.type("#i0116", mail)` is working, but `page.type('#__xmlview2--CICO_TIME-Picker-inner', '12:01')` is not?

Comment: There must be some more "SAP" magic involved. I rebuild a simple HTML page, with the `input` field you provided, and it's working like a charme.